# Can't assign a string to another string in an onchange = function()

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment, onchange, jquery-selectbox

I have this:

```
<select id="prio" class="w60">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

If i select another value, an `onchange = function()` is called:

```
var prio = document.getElementById('prio');
var string1 = "Hello";
var string2 = "";

    prio.onchange = function () 
    {
        prioIndex = prio.options[prio.selectedIndex].text;
        switch (prioIndex) 
        {
           case '1': prioIndex = " my Friend";
                     break;
           case '2': prioIndex = " my Sister and Brother";
                     break;
           case '3': prioIndex = " my Mom and Dad";
                     break;
         }
       alert(prioIndex);
       string2 = prioIndex;
     }


alert(string2);
```

The alert inside the function works fine but he will not assign the new String.

`alert(string2)` shows string2 (undefined).

I want to use `string2` outside the function. But i can't because it is never assigned. But I dont know why.

Lets say, i want to use `string2` in another onchange function...

```
var string3;
news.onchange = function () 
{ 
   string3 = string2.concat(' how are you');
   alert(string3);
}
```

and assign it to `string3`. if I want to use `string3` outside the onchange-function it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has what we call as 'callbacks'. A callback is a function executed once an action happens on the element where callback is set. Thus your `onchange` function will be executed only when you change your `prio` element on your HTML page.

That means your `prio.onchange = function () { ... }` won't execute unless you go to your HTML page, click on your select element **AND CHANGE** its value.

Thus what will be execute once that code loads into your browser is the following (*it's not fully right but will help you understand why your `string2` is not assigned as you are expecting*):

```
var prio = document.getElementById('prio');
var string1 = "Hello";
var string2 = "";
alert(string2);
```

Can you see the problem? Right!!! `string2` is empty when `alert(string2)` is called! :D

You could do what you want by passing your `string2` to another function from within your callback such as following:

```
var foo = function ( val ) {
  alert('string2 value is: ' + val);
};

prio.onchange = function () {
  prioIndex = prio.options[prio.selectedIndex].text;

  switch (prioIndex) {
    case '1': prioIndex = " my Friend";
              break;
    case '2': prioIndex = " my Sister and Brother";
              break;
    case '3': prioIndex = " my Mom and Dad";
              break;
  }

  foo(prioIndex);
}
```

However if you want to use that information in two different callbacks you could define a function to get that value whenever you need it. I mean:

```
var string2 = function () {
  var prio = document.getElementById('prio');
  prioIndex = prio.options[prio.selectedIndex].text;

  switch (prioIndex) {
    case '1': prioIndex = " my Friend";
              break;
    case '2': prioIndex = " my Sister and Brother";
              break;
    case '3': prioIndex = " my Mom and Dad";
              break;
  }

  return prioIndex;
}

var string3;
news.onchange = function () { 
  string3 = string2() + ' how are you';
  alert(string3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `alert(string2)` is not inside the click handler and will execute only once doesn't matter `prio` is clicked or not. Try moving it inside to check the value of `string2` on every click.

```
prio.onchange = function () 
    {
        prioIndex = prio.options[prio.selectedIndex].text;
        switch (prioIndex) 
        {
           case '1': prioIndex = " my Friend";
                     break;
           case '2': prioIndex = " my Sister and Brother";
                     break;
           case '3': prioIndex = " my Mom and Dad";
                     break;
         }
       alert(prioIndex);
       string2 = prioIndex;
       alert(string2);
     }
```